# How can I get the last chid public properties in extended classes in PHP?

Tags: php

```
<?php 

class S {
    public $a = 'a';
    protected $b = 'b';
    private $c = 'c';

    function get_last_child_public_properties () {
        /* HOW TO */
    }
}

class A extends S
{
    public $d = 'd';
    protected $e = 'e';
    private $f = 'f';
}

class B extends A
{
    public $g = 'public_g';
    protected $h = 'h';
    private $i = 'i';
    public $j = 'public_j';
}

$b = new B();
$props = $b->get_last_child_public_properties();
/**
 * I expect $props to be equals to :
 * Array : ['g' => 'public_g', 'j' => 'public_j']
 */
```

Comment: If you **ONLY** want the parent's public properties, you can use this code: `$reflect = new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__); return $reflect->GetProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);` inside your function `get_last_child_public_properties()`. (`var_dump` the results). Otherwise you can recursively check each class to see if a parent class exists and if not get the public properties (as it's the last class and doesn't inherit anything else) - although I don't know any uses for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at the [Relection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php)-classes in PHP.

Specifically the [getProperties()](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php)-method wich returns an array of all the properties in the object as instances of [ReflectionProperty](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionproperty.php).

```
$classInfo= new ReflectionClass($b);
foreach($classInfo->getProperties() as $prop) {
    if ($prop->isPublic() && $prop->getDeclaringClass()->name == $classInfo->name) {
        // $prop is public and is declared in class B
        $propName = $prop->name;
        $propValue = $prop->getValue($b); 

        // Since it is public, this will also work:
        $propValue = $b->$propName
        // $prop->getValue($b) will even work on protected or private properties
    }
}
```